# Artifactory OSS - Missing "eventual" binary provider?

Tags: artifactory

I am using Artifactory OSS 7.55.3, on a Windows host, attempting to set up a simple cached NFS binary store.
I cannot, for the life of me, get the "eventual" binary provider to load, I'm starting to believe it's simply not included in the release, but I see no indications of that in the documentation. Instead, Artifactory will fail to start with an error.

My binarystore.xml is as follows:

```
<config version="1">
    <chain>
        <provider id="cache-fs" type="cache-fs">
            <provider id="eventual" type="eventual">
                <provider id="file-system" type="file-system"/>
            </provider>
        </provider>
    </chain>
    <provider id="eventual" type="eventual">
        <numberOfThreads>10</numberOfThreads>
    </provider>
    <provider id="cache-fs" type="cache-fs">
        <maxCacheSize>15000000000</maxCacheSize>
    </provider>
    <provider id="file-system" type="file-system">
        <fileStoreDir>\\NAS\filestore\location</fileStoreDir>
    </provider>
</config>
```

While all docs seem to indicate this is a valid setup, Artifactory will fail to start with the following error (and a massive stacktrace that will not bother posting):

`[jfrt ] [ERROR] [1f17a84536975ce6] [ctoryContextConfigListener:126] [art-init            ] - Application could not be initialized: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.newInstance()" because "binaryProviderClass" is null`

Is there something I'm missing? Is the "eventual" binary provider not available in OSS, and is there a version where it is? The transfer to the NFS is pretty slow, making artifact upload times pretty unusably bad for large artifacts (10+gb), and it'd be great to use the local ssd as a temporary filestore to keep upload times down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventual binary provider connects to the cloud providers buckets such as S3, and Azure blob storage as explained in the [JFrog wiki page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=136876980#:%7E:text=This%20binary%20provider%20is%20not%20independent%20and%20will%20always%20be%20used%20as%20part%20of%20a%20template%20chain%20for%20a%20remote%20filestore%C2%A0that%20may%20exhibit%20upload%20latency%20(for%20example%20S3%20or%20GCS).).

As per this S3 [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/S3+Object+Storage#:%7E:text=S3%20object%20storage%20requires%20JFrog%20Container%20Registry%2C%20Pro%2C%20Enterprise%20X%2C%20or%20an%20Enterprise%2B%20license.), the cloud providers are supported for JCR, Pro, Enterprise and Enterprise+ subscriptions therefore it is expected that the eventual is not getting considered in the OSS version.

As suggested here in this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Cached+Filesystem+Binary+Provider#:%7E:text=the%20baseDataDir.-,Example%3A%20Configure%20NFS%20filestore%20with%20Caching,-The%20following%20example), you should skip using the eventual binary provider and use the cache-fs and file-system templates.

Comment: Thanks. While the wiki states the intention of the eventual provider is for cloud services, it should still be possible to use it with a filesystem provider, as [this example](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=54985075#ConfiguringtheFilestore-ChainingEventualandRetryProviders) indicates on the wiki. However it does make sense that they would remove that in OSS, which is unfortunate.

Comment: As far as I could tell, `cache-fs` only caches downloads, not uploads. When trying for myself, Artifactory places the `_pre` folder on the NFS itself while the artifact is uploaded, resulting in very slow upload times. Maybe there's some way around that issue?

Comment: I've done more digging in regards to _pre being generated on a network filestore. It appears to be a current known limitation, tracked here: [RTFACT-27180](https://jfrog.atlassian.net/browse/RTFACT-27180). A workaround appears to be to just.. symlink that folder, which feels gross but given my current requirements, is the only workaround to slow upload times on this version of Artifactory OSS.